# UMD style submodules

Tags: javascript, umd

Is it possible to seperately create submodules in an UMD style fashion? Say I have this:

```js
(function (root, factory) {
 if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  define([], factory(root));
 } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
  module.exports = factory(root);
 } else {
  root.thing = factory(root);
 }
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, function (root) {

 'use strict';

 // Object for public APIs
 var thing = {};
 thing.add = function(number) {
        return number + 2;
    };
    
    return thing;
    

});
```

What would be the best way to build up thing.sub object in a seperate file? I would like to keep my dev env clean by seperating modules this way...